# Passing value from a jsp button click to a servlet

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

ininI am bit new to jsp and servlet. I need to pass a value to a servlet on a button click. below I have mentioned my code.
web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.endpoint.oauth2.OAuth2Login</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

test.jsp

```
       function ok() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/login",
            data: 'test=' +'test',
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    }
```

below is my html code in test.jsp

```
<button id="ok" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" onclick="ok()">OK</button>
```

The servelet

```
public class OAuth2Login extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
       System.out.print("========do get fires===========");
    }
```

}

But when my test.jsp is loading it invokes the doget() of the servlet. But at the button click it does not. I dont need to invoke the servlet at the page load. But I need it on the button click. Help me to solve this out. Sorry for the ignorance. :)

Comment: Kindly share the html and js where you attach the event handler, also put on some code say alert in the success block of ajax

Comment: Arvind I put an alert in the success block. It fires. But I cant see the ajax call in the firebug. Also I have put a log in doget() of the servlet on the button click. It is also not displaying. Any help...

Comment: Kindly share the servlet code as well

Comment: Please note that I have added the servlet as well :)

Comment: Also share the `servlet` tag from web.xml for the servlet `OAuth2Logout`

Comment: You have post java code for `OAuth2Logout` instead of `OAuth2Login`

Comment: Sorry for it. I corrected it. Please have a look at

Comment: OMG.. I restarted the server and browser. Now it works. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Write your servlet mapping url in url attribute:

```
function myFun() {
         var requestPath = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";

        $.ajax({
            url: requestPath+"/login";
            data: {"data1":"value1", "data2": "value2"}
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Actually what I need is to stop invoking the servlet on the page load and invoke the servlet only at the button click. This won't stop invoking the servlet on page load.

Comment: Yes but you have already written this thing in a function. This function will not be called automatically. You will call this function on button click like onClick="javascript:myFun();"

Comment: Yes Naman. I have called the function inside a button click. No problem with that. When I view the firebug it hits the the code on button click

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: But it is not invoking the servlet.Please note I have added my html code also.

Answer (score 0):

I think in web.xml /test.jsp this is wrong in place of /test.jsp you can give yours servlet name like

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and later on button click which is in test.jsp you can call ajax function and call get method of servlet

```
function ok() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/login",
            data: 'test=' +'test',
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mytri, But by doing this it is not invoking the servlet on the button click. :(

Comment: you can call like $("button").click(function(){$.ajax({
            url: "/login",
            data: 'test=' +'test',
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });})

Comment: yes, i'm calling it button click function. Ant it hits the code inside ajax. But it does not give the output. Please note I have added my button.

Comment: You are not sending any data from servlet using get

Comment: you can write servlet like protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
      response.setContentType("application/text"); PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
       out.println("hii");
       out.close();
       out.flush();
    }

Comment: yes this is a kind of sample. The problem I had was not invoking the servlet on button click. It solved. Now I can add needful to the code. Thanks